A module signature is silently changed when it is imported. Its `eq_dec` lemma has its `=` operator changed to `eq` and no longer works
This following works as I'd expect it to. But if I place the TypeDef_S signature in another file then the apply typeDef.eq_dec. tactic fails.
Require Import Equalities.
(* Require Import TypeDefs. *)

Module Type TypeDef_S <: UsualDecidableType.
  Include UsualDecidableType.
  Parameter abstract : t -> Prop.
End TypeDef_S.

Module Def (typeDef : TypeDef_S) <: UsualDecidableType.
  Inductive definition_t : Type :=
    | Inclusion : definition_t
    | Var       : typeDef.t -> definition_t.
  Definition t : Type := definition_t.

  Theorem eq_dec : forall x y : t, 
    {x = y} + {~ x = y}.
  Proof.
    intros. 
    decide equality.
    apply typeDef.eq_dec.
  Qed.
Module Def.

I get this message:
In environment
x, y : t
t0, t1 : typeDef.t
Unable to unify "{typeDef.eq ?M1699 ?M1700} + {~ typeDef.eq ?M1699 ?M1700}" with "{t0 = t1} + {t0 <> t1}".

I've looked at the signatures used Print. The only difference I seem is that eq_dec is  forall x y : t, {x = y} + {x <> y} when the signature is local, but turns to forall x y : t, {eq x y} + {~ eq x y} when it is in another file.
But,  I thought that = was syntactic sugar that picks out the correct eq functions for its arguments, so what is happening? Unless I'm wrong about that, it looks like it should work!
(As a footnote, where do I look to find out about that { } + { } syntax? What is it called?)

I thought the standard answer to any questions about Coq's module is "don't use them".  Anyhow, {p} + {q} is a notation for sumbool.

If you want to look up definitions, then you should use Locate, like Locate "{".

I cannot reproduce your issue (I have placed the TypeDef_S module type in a separate file). What is the output of coqc --version? Can you please tell us what commands you used to compile?
